# Alternative ways for generating a random number in Fat-Free Framework

Tags: php, html, fat-free-framework

I have the following F3 htm snippet.

```
<repeat group="{{ @rooms }}" value="{{ @room }}">
  <div class="col row m12 cell white card-panel"> 
    <div class="col m4 destination valign-wrapper">
      <h4 class="valign">{{ @room }}</h4>
    </div> 
    <div class="col m8 call-number valign-wrapper">
       <h1 class="valign value">{{ rand(1,9).rand(0,9).rand(0,9).rand(0,9) }}</h1>
    </div> 
 </div>
</repeat>
```

To produce a four-digit random number, I am currently generating and concatenating four randomly generated single digit numbers. While it does work fine, it's not pretty to look at. Is there a better way to do this? I am looking for alternative ways preferably using F3, not native PHP.

Comment: Isn't that piece of code just using the native rand() function? You can slim it down to a simple call though - rand(1000, 9999).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion,